# Как отсортировать многомерный ассоциативный массив php?

Tags: php

Имеется массив следующего вида:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Александрия] => Array
                (
                    [Соборный, 1111] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 11111
                            [1] => 22222 
                            [2] => 33333
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Александрия] => Array
                (
                    [Соборный, 2222] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 11111
                            [1] => 22222 
                            [2] => 33333
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Александрия] => Array
                (
                    [Ленина, 3333] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 11111
                            [1] => 22222 
                            [2] => 33333
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Балта] => Array
                (
                    [Любомирська, 4444] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 11111
                            [1] => 22222 
                            [2] => 33333
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

Помогите его отсортировать таким образом, чтобы повторяющиеся ключи стали уникальными и в качестве своих элементов имели массивы от других таких же ключей:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Александрия] => Array
                (
                    [Соборный, 1111] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 11111
                            [1] => 22222 
                            [2] => 33333
                        ),
                    [Соборный, 2222] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 11111
                            [1] => 22222 
                            [2] => 33333
                        ),
                    [Ленина, 3333] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 11111
                            [1] => 22222 
                            [2] => 33333
                        )

                )

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Балта] => Array
                (
                    [Любомирська, 4444] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 11111
                            [1] => 22222 
                            [2] => 33333
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

Результат несколько иной получился:

```
Array
(
    [Александрия] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Соборный, 1111] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1111
                            [1] => 2222 
                            [2] => 3333
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Соборный, 2222] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1111
                            [1] => 2222 
                            [2] => 3333
                        )
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Ленина, 3333] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1111
                            [1] => 2222 
                            [2] => 3333
                        )
                )
        )
    [Балта] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Любомирська, 4444] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1111
                            [1] => 2222 
                            [2] => 3333
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

А нужен именно такой, как в примере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $result[key($value)][] = $value[key($value)];
}
var_dump($result);
```

, где `$array` - ваш массив.

**Вариант 2:**

```
$result = array();
$result2 = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $result[key($value)][key($value[key($value)])] = $value[key($value)][key($value[key($value)])];
}
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $result2[] = [$key => $value];
}
print_r($result2);
```

Comment: @Let's say Pie Результат несколько иной получился, а важно получить как в примере.

Comment: @Сергей добавил второй вариат

Comment: спасибо огромное!